openAL AL_BUFFERS_PROCESSED is always zero
I am trying to stream buffers of samples from a synthesizer (with a generic interface sampleStreamable) and I am finding that I hear a blip of audio and then it abruptly cuts off, and the value returned from AL_BUFFERS_PROCESSED is always zero, so my while (buffersProcessed) { ... } loop to dequeue and requeue buffers with new samples is never happening.
I experimented with the number of buffers and buffer sizes (frames constant) and nothing seems to make any difference.  No error is happening, but for some reason the buffer seems to only be having a short fragment of it played and then, nothing...
audio_device.h:
#include <AL/al.h>
#include <AL/alc.h>
#include <stdint.h>
class SampleStreamable;

static int const numberOfBuffers = 4;
static int const frames = 4096;
static int const sampleRate = 48000;
static int const format = AL_FORMAT_MONO16;

class AudioDevice {
public:
  explicit AudioDevice(SampleStreamable *sampleStreamable);
  void stream();
private:
  SampleStreamable *sampleStreamable;
  ALCdevice *device;
  ALCcontext *context;
  ALuint buffers[numberOfBuffers];
  ALuint source;
  int index;
  ALint buffersProcessed;
  ALint state;
  int16_t data[frames]{};
  bool streaming;
};

audio_device.cpp:
#include "audio_device.h"
#include "sample_streamable.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

AudioDevice::AudioDevice(SampleStreamable *sampleStreamable) {
  this->sampleStreamable = sampleStreamable;
  device = alcOpenDevice(NULL);
  context = alcCreateContext(device, NULL);
  alcMakeContextCurrent(context);
  assert(alGetError() == AL_NO_ERROR);
  alGenBuffers(numberOfBuffers, buffers);
  alGenSources(1, &source);
  alSourcei(source, AL_LOOPING, AL_FALSE);
}

void AudioDevice::stream() {
  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBuffers; i++) {
    sampleStreamable->process(data, frames);
    alBufferData(buffers[i], format, data, frames * sizeof(int16_t), sampleRate);
    assert(alGetError() == AL_NO_ERROR);
    alSourceQueueBuffers(source, 1, &buffers[i]);
    assert(alGetError() == AL_NO_ERROR);
  }

  ALint queuedBuffers;
  alGetSourcei(source, AL_BUFFERS_QUEUED, &queuedBuffers);
  assert(alGetError() == AL_NO_ERROR);
  assert(queuedBuffers > 0);
  alSourcePlay(source);
  assert(alGetError() == AL_NO_ERROR);

  streaming = true;
  index = 0;

  while (streaming) {
    alGetSourcei(source, AL_SOURCE_STATE, &state);
    assert(alGetError() == AL_NO_ERROR);
    assert(state == AL_PLAYING);

    alGetSourcei(source, AL_BUFFERS_PROCESSED, &buffersProcessed);
    assert(alGetError() == AL_NO_ERROR);

    while (buffersProcessed) {
      alSourceUnqueueBuffers(source, 1, &buffers[index]);
      assert(alGetError() == AL_NO_ERROR);
      sampleStreamable->process(data, frames);
      alBufferData(buffers[index], format, data, frames * sizeof(int16_t), sampleRate);
      assert(alGetError() == AL_NO_ERROR);
      alSourceQueueBuffers(source, 1, &buffers[index]);
      assert(alGetError() == AL_NO_ERROR);
      index = (index + 1) % numberOfBuffers;
      buffersProcessed--;
    }
    usleep(10 * 1000);
  }


why would someone vote to close this?????????
